# Unable to delete PDF file after sending email

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file, email, email-attachments

My code process the information an a website then exports it to word documents then converts it to PDF and proceeds to attach it onto an email code. I've managed to send the email with the PDF but have problems with the file management. In this case I would want to delete the files in the folder namely, the generated word and PDF document. The code runs and was able to delete the word document but unable to delete the PDF document.

The error when I manually tried to delete the file was "The action can't be completed because the file is open in webdev.webserver40.exe". Currently running on debug mode and wish to run this on an IIS in the future.

Below is the snippet of my email code

```
Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
            Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
            Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False

            e_mail = New MailMessage()                
            e_mail.Subject = "Job Completed "
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
            e_mail.Body = msg
            e_mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(Server.MapPath("PDF\" + filename + ".pdf")))
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
            Smtp_Server.Dispose()
            e_mail.Attachments.Clear()
            e_mail.Dispose()
```

Removed authentication and sending address. Below is the code to delete the files

```
Dim filePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("PDF"))
        For Each filePath As String In filePaths
            File.Delete(filePath)
        Next
```

below is the class file that is used to convert the pdf

```
    Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class ConvertWordToPDF
    Public Sub convertToPDF(strFileName As String)
        ' Create a new Microsoft Word application object
        Dim word As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()

        ' C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value
        Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        ' Get list of Word files in specified directory
        Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("PDF"))
        Dim wordFiles As FileInfo() = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.docx")
        word.Visible = False
        word.ScreenUpdating = False

        ' Cast as Object for word Open method
        Dim filename As [Object] = DirectCast(wordFiles(0).FullName, [Object])
        'Dim fileName As Object = strFileName

        ' Use the dummy value as a placeholder for optional arguments
        Dim doc As Document = word.Documents.Open(fileName, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, _
         oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, _
         oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing)
        doc.Activate()

        Dim outputFileName As Object = wordFiles(0).FullName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf")
        Dim fileFormat As Object = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF

        ' Save document into PDF Format
        doc.SaveAs(outputFileName, fileFormat, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, _
         oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, _
         oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing)

        ' Close the Word document, but leave the Word application open.
        ' doc has to be cast to type _Document so that it will find the
        ' correct Close method.                
        Dim saveChanges As Object = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges
        DirectCast(doc, _Document).Close(saveChanges, oMissing, oMissing)

        doc = Nothing

        ' word has to be cast to type _Application so that it will find
        ' the correct Quit method.
        DirectCast(word, _Application).Quit(oMissing, oMissing, oMissing)
        word = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Edit:
Added code to check if the file is locked

```
Protected Overridable Function IsFileLocked(file As FileInfo) As Boolean
    Dim stream As FileStream = Nothing

    Try
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
    Catch generatedExceptionName As IOException
        'the file is unavailable because it is:
        'still being written to
        'or being processed by another thread
        'or does not exist (has already been processed)
        Return True
    Finally
        If stream IsNot Nothing Then
            stream.Close()
        End If
    End Try

    'file is not locked
    Return False
End Function
```

it returned false after the pdf was created.

Comment: Chech the properties of the folder that contains your file. Is it set to "everyone", or at least is it allowed for "network service" (the IIS account)?

Comment: like in the security tab of the folder?

Comment: yes, properties > security.

Comment: well i doubt it has anything to do with the folder as my word document was successfully deleted from the same folder but the PDF was unable to be deleted. I need a code of some sort or the dispose isnt working properly.

Comment: Alright, can you put your pdf generator function? It seems that the file is not closed properly.

Comment: all right will do .. its in the edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56177/discussion-between-nicolas-henrard-and-user2552331).

Comment: Need to bump up my post cos its still not able to delete the PDF after the mail is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested a scenario where i was able to reproduce the problem. I was able to fix it by adding the attachment as a stream rather than just a path to the file. Just remember to close the stream one way or another.

This code gives the error you descriped:

```
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("...") 

    message.Attachments.Add(New Attachment("c:\myfile.txt"))
    smtp.Send(message)

    File.Delete("c:\myfile.txt")
```

This works:

```
   Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("...")

    Using reader As New StreamReader("C:\myfile.txt")
        Dim a As New Attachment(reader.BaseStream, "myfile.txt")
        message.Attachments.Add(a)

        smtp.Send(message)
    End Using      

    File.Delete("c:\myfile.txt")
```